# how to get top 10 records from linked server object in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to get top 10 from linked server object. When I use openquery it will return the entire result after that it return that top 10 counts but I want only 10 records. don't want to process all the record. Is there any way to get this result.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current code attempt. Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using (Mentioning "linked server" seems to indicate "Microsoft SQL Server" though).

Comment: thanks for your response jarlh,
Select top 10 * from openquery([linked server],'select * from tablename')

Comment: thanks for your reply a_horse_with_no_name,
I am using Microsoft SQL Server